# Validation Error: Value Error : font-family 'Neue' is not a font-family value : Helvetica 'Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif

Tags: html, css, fonts, w3c-validation

So I decided to start optimizing my site and fixing things, and this came up in the W3C Validator.

Value Error : font-family "Neue" is not a font-family value : "Montserrat",Helvetica "Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif

Value Error : font-family 'Neue' is not a font-family value : Helvetica 'Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif

Now, I declared my font families as follows:

```
font-family: "Montserrat",Helvetica "Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-family: Helvetica 'Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
```

The difference between the two being the usage of double quotes and single quotes " vs '
And using a Google web font in the first one being "Monteserrat"

How can I fix this and make it validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each family needs to be all in quotes, or not at all. So you can say:

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
```

or:

```
font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
```

However, you shouldn't just quote the `Neue` part.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family

Comment: Would it be okay to encapsulate all of the font arguments in quotes as well? How about just the first two? Thanks for the help by the way! =)

Comment: You can choose to quote or not-quote any that you like, as long as the names don't contain anything crazy like punctuation. If they're all simple names like this, I wouldn't quote any.

Comment: Any actual font family name may be quoted if desired, but not the generic names like `sans-serif` (they do not work if quoted).